# Radius of Convergence for a power series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Q) The radius of convergence of the power series$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(3m)!}{(m!)^3}x^{3m}$$ is:   _____________

**My Approach :-**
Power series $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }c_{n}(x-a)^{n}$$ converges if :

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left | \frac{c_{n+1}*(x-a)^{n+1}}{c_{n}*x^n} \right | < 1$$

Here, power series is defined as $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty }\frac{(3m)!}{(m!)^3}\;x^{3m}$$

So, given power series converges if :

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty } \left | \frac{\frac{((3(m+1))!)*x^{(3(m+1))}}{((m+1)!)^3}}{\frac{((3m)!)*x^{3m}}{(m!)^3}} \right | < 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty } \left | \frac{\frac{((3m+3)!)*x^{3m}x^3}{((m+1)(m!))^3}}{\frac{((3m)!)*x^{3m}}{(m!)^3}} \right | < 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty } \left | \frac{(3m+3)(3m+2)(3m+1)((3m)!)x^{3m}x^3 (m!)^3}{(m+1)^3(m!)^3 ((3m)!)x^{3m} } \right | < 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty } \left | \frac{(3m+3)(3m+2)(3m+1)x^3 }{(m+1)^3 } \right | < 1$$

On Dividing by $m^3$ in both numerator and denominator :

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty } \left | \frac{(3 + \frac{3}{m})(3+ \frac{2}{m})(3+\frac{1}{m})x^3 }{(1+\frac{1}{m})(1+\frac{1}{m})(1+\frac{1}{m})} \right | < 1$$

$$\Rightarrow | (3x)^3| < 1 \\ \Rightarrow -1 < (3x)^3 < 1$$

$$\Rightarrow (-1)^{1/3} < 3x < 1^{1/3}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{(-1)^{1/3}}{3} < x < \frac{1^{1/3}}{3}$$

So, Radius of Convergence will be $\frac{1^{1/3}}{3}$

Please tell me whether it is correct or not and if it is wrong then please correct it.

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Hadamard's theorem.

Comment: In this case $1^{1/3}=1$.

Comment: @Feng Shao, can you please explain why $1^{1/3}$ should be taken as $1$. It is a cube root of unity.

Comment: @ankit Because $x$ is real.

Comment: @ankit The radius of convergence is a nonnegative real number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate way:

By applying [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$ n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n $$ we have:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{(3m)!}{(m!)^3}\right)^{1/3m}&\sim\left(\frac{\sqrt{3m}\ 3^{3m}}{\sqrt{m}}\right)^{1/3m}\sim 3
\end{align}
Hence the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a_m=\frac{(3m)!}{(m!)^3}\;x^{3m}$$
$$\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}=\frac{3 (3 m+1) (3 m+2) }{(m+1)^2}x^3$$ When $m\to \infty$\ this ratio tends to $27x^3=(3x)^3$ and then a radius of $\frac 13$.